How to fill ds160 if I am currently enrolled in a educational degree but also full-time employee
I am currently enrolled in a educational degree that only has formal processes pending but I have not been granted an educational degree yet. In parallel I started my full-time job at a company which is now sponsoring my visit to the USA. DS160 form only allows me to fill the current employer or the current education. I am primarily an employee that has a pending degree completion.
I tried adding my education as previous education but it requires an end-date which is not after the present date, how do I give the most accurate representation of my case?

Cross post here: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/190692/ds-160-b1-b2-work-education-i-work-full-time-study-part-time-f-1-ref (no answer either, though)

If you have completed absolutely all the requirements for your degree, with no possibility of being required to do anything else, and are literally only waiting to get the certificate, I would enter the end date of the degree as the last time you did anything for it. End of last course, last exam, or last piece of paperwork filed.
